# Are One-Click Desktop Notifications Possible?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm wondering are one click desktop notifications possible?

What I mean is sort of like click-jacking on FB. Where they press a button on my site and the script automatically presses "Allow" for them for example. Instead of them having to press a button, and then the browser asking them again.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Permissions prompts cannot be bypassed. That would make them useless.